# how to specify correct configuration for structuremap for mvc decoupled app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, structuremap

I'm trying to convert my first mvc app, across to a decoupled framework.

I have the following layers
MVC Web layer , Controller Layer , Domain Layer , Service Layer , Data Layer, and a Shared Project

I've got testing working alright, using structuremap, and injecting dependancies.
My major hurdle is this.

I am working off a oracle database, and need to remap the schemas contained in the entity framework at runtime.  I have this working through using the BrandonHayes Adapter (Ive modified it slightly).

for my service layer testing, I mock the object context, so it doesnt run against a real database.

```
         private Mock<ICLObjectContext> _clmock = new Mock<ICLObjectContext>();
```

for my data unit testing I do something like this, so that I can test against my test database, and using transactions, I can roll back after testing.

```
        //This allows us to remap the schema
        Dictionary<string,string> mappingschemas = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        mappingschemas.Add("CLAPORTAL","CLAPORTALTEST");
        mappingschemas.Add("QCTL","QTEST");
         _context = new CLObjectContext(ec, mappingschemas);
         ObjectFactory.Inject(typeof(ICLObjectContext), _context);
```

This works well.  The issue is When I try and run the application for real.

I've had to remove this constructor, and only leave a simple 0 parameter constructor so that Structuremap can create the object context at runtime, and hence can not do any schema mapping.

Because the Web project has no reference to the Data Layer, and hence knows nothing about the ICLObjectContext, how do I tell structuremap, via some configuration, I want to create a new dictionary with mapping schema x to schema y,

The service layer has a reference to the data layer, so I'm guessing I need to do it in there, since the web project, can reference the service layer.

Would this be about right? Meh I've just got myself sort of caught up and cant see a way out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once again, after writing out the question, It helped me to come up with a solution.

I simply created an interface called ISchemaResolver, and made it part of the shared project.

I then placed this in the constructor for my entityadapter class.

On the web project, I just created a class called AppSettingsSchemaResolver, which uses app settings to set up the dictionary, and then pass that in via global.asax, when i wire up my dependancies, ie

```
              //Now also set up our schema mapping stuff.
  ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ISchemaResolver>().Add<AppSettingsSchemaResolver>());
```